# numerical range of a parametrized matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to find the numerical range of a parametrized matrix $A(t)$ such that
$(a_ij)=\exp (b_{ij}t)$ where $B=(b_{ij})$ is a real matrix.
does anyone know something about the numerical range of a parametrized matrix?

thanks